# JavaFX "Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application" when trying to run fx in vscode

Tags: java, json, javafx, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a project with a couple friends and we're using vscode so that we can use git efficiently (it's for a school project so IDE is non-negotiable, don't tell me to use a different one) and we're having an issue where neither of them can run this javafx application that I've got in there for testing right now. I was having trouble running it at first and was getting the same error, but I fixed it this morning and now any javafx file I put in there will run fine for me, as long as I have the correct vmargs in the json. However, they're both getting this error when they try to run:

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

It doesn't say which components are missing or how to fix it which is annoying, but I'm kind of at a loss for what to do. I was having this error, then I added vmArgs to the json to load the proper modules, and it fixed the issue. One thing I've noticed is that when they try to run the file on their end, the json adds new configurations without them telling it to. Even if they delete it, it comes back. But this doesn't happen for me. What am I missing to fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54349894/javafx-11-with-vscode

Comment: Have you tried the solution @Sedrick mentioned? The answer is very detailed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23956861/how-to-span-columns-of-a-gridpane-manually-in-javafx

Answer (score 0):

you can run from cmd/terminal with:
cd to ur jar directory
and run:
java -jar --module-path /path/to/javafx --add-modules=javafx.controls(or whatever jars u need from the fx lib) filename.jar